How to add continuation alerts to the index of a book?
I am preparing a textbook for publication using imakeidx, and the index is quite long, with many topics and subtopics.  It's common for the list of subtopics under a main topic to be split across page and column boundaries (see example).   When this happens, I want to add a line to the top of the column receiving the overflow, saying "main topic continued".  I have seen a number of commercially published longer textbooks do this, but I cannot find any LaTeX package that implements this seemingly common feature.   I realize that I can manually edit the .ind file, but that seems like an unsatisfactory solution unless there's really no way to achieve it automatically.


please provide a minimal working example (MWE). I figured you must have been asked for this a bunch of times before, but evidence to bear my assumption out turned out to be surprisingly scanty.

In the 3rd edition of the LaTeX Companion, Volume I, page 394, there is a proposed solution for dictionary headers that might work for you?
\documentclass{article}

\NewMarkClass{idxmark}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{}
\newcommand\combinemarks{%
    \IfMarksEqualTF{idxmark}{first}{last}
    {\FirstMark{idxmark}}% equal values
    {\FirstMark{idxmark}---%
        \LastMark{idxmark}}}
\chead{\combinemarks} \cfoot{\thepage}
\newcommand\idxitem[1]{\par\vspace{8pt}%
    \textbf{#1}\InsertMark{idxmark}{#1}%
    \quad\ignorespaces}
    
\begin{document}
\idxitem{galley} Text formatted but not
cut into pages.
\idxitem{OR} Output routine.
\idxitem{mark} An object in the galley
used to communicate with the OR.
\idxitem{running header} page title
changing with page contents.
\end{document}

(The LaTeX Companion, Third Edition – Part I, Frank Mittelbach, LaTeX Project, Mainz, Germany & Ulrike Fischer, LaTeX Project, Bonn, Germany, With contributions by Joseph Wright, Addison-Wesley, 2023)
